# Telepaths with different abilities, wind up on moon

Tags: story-identification, teleportation, telepathy, moon, telekinesis

The book/story was written before 1980 (at least).  It centers on a young woman (on Earth) who can read thoughts.  She has to hide this fact, because the authorities have discovered that some people have psychic abilities, of different kinds.  Some can read minds, some can transmit thoughts, some can do telekinesis.  She gets into contact with a secret group of "psions" (not the term in the book/story).  Eventually she discoverers that she is a super-high-level "psion", but not before she is caught and sent to a "prison" on the Moon.  In the end, they all teleport away with the help of some friendly "psionic" aliens.

Another detail: Young female protagonist's main "psion" friend is a guy who has all the talents, which is unusual and indicates that he is extra powerful. I think he is best at transmitting thoughts. She has a hard time meeting him in person because he is confused about how far from him she is.

Comment: Thanks to whoever upvoted.  More importantly, I definitely will appreciate any leads.

Comment: Another detail: Young female protagonist's main "psion" friend is a guy who has all the talents, which is unusual and indicates that he is extra powerful. I think he is best at transmitting thoughts.  She has a hard time meeting him in person because he is confused about how far from him she is.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a bit like Ubik (Philip K Dick).

[wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubik)

The young female has the ability to undo events by changing the past. A group of "anti-psis" go to the moon. Not an exact match but some similarities.

Comment: It's not Ubik. There is an expedition to the moon the "anti-psis" but is not a rescue mission of any sorts and the focus of the story is not a young lady, but a man trying to figure out why the future is rescinding to the past.